# Approver comments in workflow emails

Tags: 2013, designer-workflow, email

I'm working with a SP '13 designer workflow which is simple. One approval task was created for a user. After this approval task, I need a email which states comments and a notification of approval or rejection. I'm unable to find a look-up which post the approver's comments in the notification email after the task. I have tested almost every look up available in designer, and they either come up blank or cause my workflow to error. I'm able to see the comments in the hidden history list as well as the task list, but I need to have them included in the notification email after the task has been completed( look-ups to the columns in these list still aren't working).

Comment: Are you using the default Approval workflow? That should already include notification emails. Also, you mention you've tried almost every lookup; does that include the workflow variables?

Comment: Hey Aaron, I'm using a custom designer workflow. I need the comments displayed in a email following completion of the task, not in the notification task email. However I created a test workflow and created 2 task back to back, and comments from the 1st task are not included in the secondary task notification. Email look-up's in "13 designer allow me to look up workflow variables as a data source, however field from source only list "taskid", and "outcome1"  as options there is no field for comments.

Answer (score 3):

As u said ur using an sp2013 custom wf.
So, lets follow some steps to get the easy solution.

1. Create a column as named 'parentId' in task list.
2. When ur emailing with the approver msg, get the comments from the task list and to do that select the task by filtering with the parentId equal to item id.

I hope it will help. Let me know if u have any confusion.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Approvers comments field in the dropdown menu under Current Item

Thanks.